# How To Set Java Array Length

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a little bit confused.

I am writing a program in which I need an
`array` to save the values but the values are user defined and I want to print the array but it  prints the
array value:

> 1
>   0
>   0
>   0
>   0
>   0

Because I define the length of the array. So what can I do to remove the extra `0` and print only user defined values?

Comment: Please post your code so we can better help.  Anyway you could set a counter to store number of user input and use it as a upper bound for you print loop

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions

1. You can use a java.util.ArrayList to store your entries. ArrayList can grow and shrink to whatever size you need
2. You can first create an int[] larger than you think you'd ever use, then define `int arrLength` and use that to try your array size

Comment: A third approach is to define an int[] which is larger than will be needed, and use the first item to store the length.  This isn't a "normal" technique, but it is in many cases the most efficient especially if code will need to create space for items and then fill them in random order, something none of the other types can accommodate very well.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a dynamically sized collection I would recommend using a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (like [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)).

This is a simple example of how it works:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);

System.out.println("My List:" + list);
```

Output:

```
My List:[1, 2, 3]
```

You have to import `java.util.ArrayList` and `java.util.List` to be able to use them.

You can also iterate over the `List` like this:

```
for(int val : list) {
    System.out.println("value: " +val);
}
```

Output:

```
value: 1
value: 2
value: 3
```

or iterate with an index:

```
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
    System.out.println("value " + i + ": " + list.get(i));
}
```

Output:

```
value 0: 1
value 1: 2
value 2: 3
```

<sup>(Note that the indexes are 0-based; i.e. they start at 0, not 1)</sup>

For further information, please read the two Javadocs linked above for `List` and `ArrayList`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dynamic array, which is implemented by java as [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

An alternative (worse one though, in most cases), is find out the "desired" length of the array, and get only a part of it by creating a new array with the [`Arrays.copyOfRange()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(int[],%20int,%20int)) method

It also seems you are using a custom printing method, which you can halt after reaching a certain index.

---

As a side note, you can print an array easily by converting the array to `String` with [`Arrays.toString(array)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int[])) - and printing this String

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is like:

```
List list = new ArrayList(5);
```